# RSpec only first `it` block passes and Capybara or Selenium redirects page

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I've got a fairly simple testing scenario configured with RSpec, Capybara, and Selenium:

```
require './spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'test' do
  title = 'My title'

  context 'When I navigate to my page' do
    before(:all) do
      visit 'http://foo.com/'
    end

    it "the page title is #{title}" do
      expect(page.title).to eq(title)
    end

    it 'there is an input for email' do
      expect(page).to have_css('#login-u')
    end

    it 'there is an input for password' do
      expect(page).to have_css('#login-p')
    end

    it 'there is an input for access token' do
      expect(page).to have_css('#login-a')
    end
  end
end
```

The page is navigated to, the first `it` passes, and then the page redirects to a blank page and the last three `it` blocks fail.

Interestingly, if I move every `expect` statement into the first `it` block, then the test passes:

```
require './spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'test' do
  title = 'My title'

  context 'When I navigate to my page' do
    before(:all) do
      visit 'http://foo.com/'
    end

    it "the page title is #{title}" do
      expect(page.title).to eq(title)
      expect(page).to have_css('#login-u')
      expect(page).to have_css('#login-p')
      expect(page).to have_css('#login-a')
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the contents of my **Gemfile**:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'capybara'
```

And here is my **spec_helper.rb**:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  From what I understand, it is a best practice to have one `expect` per `it`, so I really want to do it the first way if I can get it working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried moving the before block outside the context block? before hooks are contextual in nature [RSpec::Core::Hooks#before](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec%2FCore%2FHooks%3Abefore)

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work.  I moved the `before` block out of the `context` and the first `it` passed but the other three `it`s failed.  :(

Comment: Played with it again.  I moved the `before` out of the `context` and changed it from `before(:all)` to `before(:each)`.  This works, but it revisits the page four separate times now.  I understand that is how `before(:each)` works, but it seems like `before(:all)` should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before(:all)` runs the block once before evaluating the 'it' blocks.  This isn't going to work with a normal Capybara setup since Capybara resets the session after each test which includes a `visit 'about:blank'`.  If you want to keep one `expect` per `it` then your initial visit needs to be in a `before(:each)` block.

That being said, sticking to one expect per test doesn't make a lot of sense in feature tests where you should be testing page behavior (visit page, fill in fields, click buttons, etc) and a given test is going to expect multiple things to happen.  Your tests look they really belong as view tests and not feature tests.

Additionally, you should be using the `have_title` matcher rather than using `eq` with page.title

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  What do you mean about a view test versus a feature test?  I've never heard of a view test.  For whatever it is worth, this is probably the simplest test I'll have others will log in and interact with the page more.

Comment: @vulpix RSpec supports multiple types of tests - one of those is view specs - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/view-specs/view-spec - which are for testing things that should be rendered to a page.  Capybara includes its matchers into view specs so you can do things like `expect(rendered).to have_css('#login')`  .  It doesn't make much sense to have a feature test that just tests a login box exists since you should have a feature test that fills in that box, and if the box was missing it would error when you try to fill it.

Comment: @vulpix If this answered the question for you, don't forget to accept it (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered.

Comment: The part about view tests didn't make sense to me, so I was waiting for you to explain that before I accepted your answer.  Thanks for explaining it.